# cURL - Fetch data only if html page (link)

Tags: php, html, curl, web-crawler

I am building a CSS Optimizer website, in this I will offer a option where a user submits a Website URL and on backend, server will parse all the `anchors` and `link` tags within that domain. So this will enable the site to concatenate + compress the `css` which may be unique on all different pages.

As all my website needs is `anchor (html)` and `<link>` what should I do to avoid fetching links that are `non-html (like .doc, .pdf)` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can reply on just the extensions of targets. Clean URLs don't often have extensions at the end, content might be generated.

You should probably do an HTTP `HEAD` on every URL and then check the Content-Type which is returned.

Comment: Yes I know about `CURLOPT_NOBODY` but this means that I will have to make 2 requests for each `<a>` any other option?

Comment: Yes but with the HEAD, you don't have to fetch the entire resource. Just the basic information.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the mime type of the related link with `mime_content_type()`?

Comment: results are same as curl. (infact its bit slower than making 2 requests from curl) but it was a very appreciated suggestion.